# How to do an INSERT in SQL Server from a string containing a specific column

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that receives a string with the values of a specific column I want and then insert one row per each value, divided by "," .

For instance:

```
    --The string I mentioned
    @Objectid = '15, 21, 23, 53'.
    --Then I wish to insert those values into a table like for instance
    #Result( ID bigint, AppID bigint, ObjectID bigint)
```

So I wished to perform an insert on that table, and place the
values of each @Objectid onto a different row of #Result and on the 
column ObjectID, while at the same time, filling other columns with 
values I have stored in variables on the same stored procedure. Is there a way to do this? And if so, is there a way to do this without the usage of a cursor?

Comment: use a table valued parameter and split in code before passing to proc

Comment: There are ways in SQL to split up a string (eg when delimeted by a comma) - have a look at [existing Q & A](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%23sql-server+split+a+string). However, it would be much better if you can split up your Id's beforehand. You won't need a `CURSOR`, but will probably need to use a `WHILE` loop to execute the `INSERT` statement multiple times. What is your source system (ie how do you get the list of Id's)?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server? In 2016 there is the STRING_SPLIT function that you can use

Comment: I'm calling the procedure from an web application from c#, and I'm running on SQL Server 2012. I could split the values before reaching the procedure but my main purpose is to do most operations through SQL and try to leave a minimum on the C# code. Thank you for the suggestions however

Comment: Use the right tools for the right jobs. C# has access to lots of useful string formatting/manipulation code. T-SQL is *severely* limited when it comes to string processing functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Objectid varchar(max);
set @Objectid = '15, 21, 23, 53';
set @Objectid = Replace(@Objectid, ',', '.');

SELECT ParseName(@Objectid, 4) As ID , 
       ParseName(@Objectid, 3) As AppID , 
       ParseName(@Objectid, 2) As ObjectID, 
       ParseName(@Objectid, 1)  As ObjectID2
```

Comment: please query use like above examle

Comment: Please note that this is an abuse of the `PARSENAME` function and it's also not extensible to more than 4 elements, so it's not a general solution to the problem either.

Comment: This does not solve my problem and isn't what I was looking for at all, thank you for trying nonetheless

Comment: sorry so this will try other solutions